# Can Kendo Grid use client side filtering with server side paging/sorting?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use ServerOperation(true) on my Kendo Grid DataSource to perform server side paging/sorting.  I have some columns declared with the Filterable method, which causes server side requests to populate the type ahead.  I would like these Filterable columns to just work client side with whatever data is available on the current page.  Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

I use [`toODataString`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/data-query/api/toODataString/) on the grid's `State` object on the front end, which queries my OData v4 ASP.NET Web Service running on IIS (server side).